# Как переписать вместо findIndex() чтобы было только способом map()?

Tags: методы

Есть обьект и функция которая работает как switch:

```js
let todoItems = [{
  checked: false,
  id: 33333
}];

function toggleDone(key) {
  const index = todoItems.findIndex(item => item.id === Number(key));
  todoItems[index].checked = !todoItems[index].checked;
  return todoItems[index];
}

console.log(toggleDone(33333)) // { checked: false, id: 33333 }
console.log(toggleDone(33333)) // { checked: true, id: 33333 }
```

На выходе при вводе одних и тех же данных выводим разные значения! (`true` / `false`).
Как также сделать с `map()` ?

Comment: Я ничего не понял.